# CSS Grid Display Line Numbers Hidden

Tags: css, firefox, css-grid, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

For some reason, when I toggle on the CSS grid display line numbers, the numbers keep staying hidden at the top. I'm using Firefox Developer Edition.

css grid dev tools:

[image: css grid dev tools]

Without adding margin
[grid number hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9DfD.png)

Added margin
[grid numbers shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e2Lt.png)

Comment: Please provide more information and paste code. It would be greate if yo uwould provide demo using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It has nothing to do with code, but the grid view option in dev tools. I have updated 2 new screenshots. As you can see I have to add a margin so that I can be able to see grid numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the line numbers are not shown is a bug in the DevTools. It is reported as [bug 1396666](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396666). See also [bug 1382284](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1382284), which asks for sticky line numbers.